# Entity Framework database first: Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building a console app in C# which uses Entity Framework to access some tables of plots in an SQL Server database. It looks at a table called ControlTable, sees which plots are missing soil analysis, asynchronously goes to the Plots table and gets those plots' coordinates, then makes an API call, returns soil data and saves it in the PlotSoilChemistry table.

I've added all these tables with Entity Framework Database First, and can see them in an .edmx model.

The code fine, updates everything, and then throws an SqlException:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot find the object "[dbo.PlotSoilChemistry" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.'
```

The table exists-I can see it in SSMS and in the .edmx file. I've tried deleting and re-adding the model, and the error does not go away. Suggestions?

Comment: If the object does exist, could it be that you don't have permissions, as the error suggests? In other words, does the user under which you connect to your database have the necessary permissions on that table?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem-I'm using "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PlotSoilChemistry] ON" and had an extra square bracket work its way in there. D'oh!